# Friend declaration grants access only to some members

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend, partial-specialization

In the following code, all specializations of the `Derived` class should be friends of each other. It works to some extent; however, the friend declaration seems to grant access only to some members.

```
class Base { protected: int i; };
template <typename T> class Derived;
template <typename T> class Derived<Derived<T>> : public Base {
  template <typename U> friend class Derived;
  int i;
 public:
  void f() {
    Derived<Derived<float>> d;
    (void)d.i;       // works fine, although i is private
    (void)d.Base::i; // error: 'int Base::i' is protected
  }
};
int main() { Derived<Derived<int>>().f(); }
```

Why can `Derived<Derived<int>>` access `Derived<Derived<float>>::i` (which is private member) but not `Derived<Derived<float>>::Base::i` (which is a protected member)?

I suspect the problem may have to do with the fact that a partial specialization is involved. However, strictly speaking, the friend declaration does not declare a partial specialization. Moreover, if the partial specialization was the reason, why does `d.i` still work?

In short, why does `d.i` work but not `d.Base::i` and how to fix it?

Edit: Interestingly, if we remove the partial specialization as below, both `d.i` and `d.Base::i` work fine.

```
class Base { protected: int i; };
template <typename T> class Derived : public Base {
  template <typename U> friend class Derived;
  int i;
 public:
  void f() {
    Derived<float> d;
    (void)d.i;       // works fine
    (void)d.Base::i; // also works fine
  }
};
int main() { Derived<int>().f(); }
```

Comment: Being a friend of `Derived` doesn't make you a friend of `Base`. And `Base::i` isn't visible in `Derived` because of the new variable shadowing it.

Comment: @BoPersson Well, but if we remove the partial specialization, both `d.i` and `d.Base::i` work fine (I edited the question since I cannot post code with multiple lines in the comments). How does that go with your explanation?

Comment: Where's the definition of the unspecialized `Derived` template?

Comment: @Spencer There isn't any. Both snippets in the question are minimal and _complete_ examples. Verify them with your favorite compiler.

Comment: For what it's worth, Clang and MSVC accept the first program; only GCC complains.